# sql group by - display all rows

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm working on some basic stat tracking website for some buddies and would like to organize the individual player pages a bit more.

My plan is to have separate tables print out based on the date they played so they can see games from specific dates a bit easier.

Im very new to php and have discovered the "GROUP BY" and while this correctly groups by date, it only returns one row... is there a way to get every row within the "GROUP BY?"

Heres what I have now:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE player='$thePlayer' GROUP BY whenPlayed";
```

Comment: You should use `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`, e.g. `SELECT * FROM games WHERE player = '$thePlayer' ORDER BY whenPlayed ASC`

Comment: This was my original plan, however, I was struggling with the logic of getting separate tables to print for separate dates.

Comment: Keep track of the current date...

Comment: 4 games were played on the 17th, 6 games were played on the 24th. The current date really wouldnt serve me any purpose.

Comment: Keep track of the current / last date in the loop and take action when it changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get data
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE player = '$thePlayer' ORDER BY whenPlayed";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


$data = array();
// Iterate over data, use 'whenPlayed` as a key to group your data
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['whenPlayed'], $data)) {
        $data[$row['whenPlayed']] = array();
    }
    $data[$row['whenPlayed']][] = $row;
}
```

Then to display it in a list, for example:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($data as $date => $games): ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $date ?>:
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($games as $game): ?>
            <li><?php echo print_r($game, true) ?></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to first `ORDER` your rows for `whenPlayed` ascending or descending order and add where condition if you need row slot for individual date or something else.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE player='$thePlayer' ORDER BY whenPlayed ASC";
```